# SQL find char in data

Tags: sql, find

i have a table have column that contain number and character.
how can i find the line that only contain the character?
normaly this column can not be filled by character, but the user had make a many mistake

example:

```
Phone_Number
------------
02.23.35.65
02.32.65.87 EZERT
066565654
54541214 RTYR
```

i want to get this result:

```
02.32.65.87 EZERT
54541214 RTYR
```

i have tried with `where Phone_Number like '%[0-9]%'` 
and `where Isnumeric(Phone_Number) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select phone_number
from table
where  phone_number like '%[A-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE Phone_Number LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE PATINDEX('%[^.0-9]%', Phone_Number) > 0
```

The query ensures that only valid characters are digits 0-9 and a comma. Meaning if any other than valid (not only [A-Z]) characters are present it will catch it.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe866/5)** demo